# Android : Sending image as byte[] by Http Get or Post Request

Tags: java, android, soap, httprequest

I need to upload image to the web server and it require the ImageContent to be in byte[] at the documentation it said base64Binary but i tried base64 encoded string and no use

that is my class :

```
private class background extends AsyncTask<byte[],Void,String> {

    String url = "http://www.sample.com/_mobfiles/CLS_Account.asmx/UploadImage";
    String charset = "UTF-8";  
    String param1 = "jpg";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... params) {

        try {
            String query = String.format("ImageContent=%s&imageExtenstion=%s", params[0], URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());
            }
            String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            String charset = null;
            for (String param : contentType.replace(" ", "").split(";")) {
                if (param.startsWith("charset=")) {
                    charset = param.split("=", 2)[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (charset != null) {
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response, charset))) {
                    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int nRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[16384];
                while ((nRead = response.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
                }
                buffer.flush();
                byte[] arr = buffer.toByteArray();
                String decoded = new String(arr, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(decoded);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

that return (java.io.FileNotFoundException)

and the Base64 Encoded return (java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: Object moved)

Here is the Doc :

---

HTTP GET

The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
GET /_mobfiles/CLS_Account.asmx/UploadImage?ImageContent=base64Binary&imageExtenstion=string HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sample.com
```

and the response is like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">string</string>
```

---

HTTP POST

The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /_mobfiles/CLS_Account.asmx/UploadImage HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sample.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

ImageContent=base64Binary&imageExtenstion=string
```

and the response is like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">string</string>
```

Comment: where should i write that ?

Comment: try <img src="data:image/yyy;base64,xxxxxx"/> on a browser where yyy refers to image type and xxxx to your base64 encoded image Try it here https://jsfiddle.net/o4mut2uv/ and share. Use a small image to be quick.

Comment: it shows the image ok

Comment: can you try a really small image 1~KB or so using your technique. Whose server is it? Generally GET requests have size limits and converting image to base 64 itself drastically increases size so there is a possibility you size might be a problem. Try manually visiting the link. What is supposed to be the expected behavior?

Comment: it is supposed to return xml with string object containing auto generated image name

Comment: when i visit it manually it says "System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAAB4CAIAAAD6wG44AAAAA3N... to System.Byte."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way but to send the whole SOAP envelope

So from a background thread `AsyncTask` i called `callSOAPWebService(String data)` when executed

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 150, 150, false);
resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
new ImageUpload().execute(encoded);
```

from the UI thread

and on background

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            callSOAPWebService(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
```

and the `callSOAPWebService` is as follow

```
private boolean callSOAPWebService(String data) {
        OutputStream out = null;
        int respCode;
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(GetData.NonOpDomain);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            do {
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("SendChunked", "True");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("UseCookieContainer", "True");
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(true);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", getReqData(data).length + "");
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(100 * 1000);
                // httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                out = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                if (out != null) {
                    out.write(getReqData(data));
                    out.flush();
                }
                respCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.e("respCode", ":" + respCode);
            } while (respCode == -1);

            // If it works fine
            if (respCode == 200) {
                try {
                    InputStream responce = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    String str = convertStreamToString(responce);
                    System.out.println(".....data....." + str);
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(is, null);
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out = null;
            }
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                httpURLConnection = null;
            }
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

and the helper method

```
public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text = null;
    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name = myParser.getName();

            switch (event) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (name.equals("UploadImageResult")) {
                        uploadedImage = text;
                        uploadedImage = uploadedImage.replace("\"", "");
                    }
                    break;
            }
            event = myParser.next();
        }
        parsingComplete = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String createSoapHeader() {
    String soapHeader;

    soapHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
            + "<soap:Envelope "
            + "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""
            + " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""
            + " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" + ">";
    return soapHeader;
}

public static byte[] getReqData(String data) {
    StringBuilder requestData = new StringBuilder();

    requestData.append(createSoapHeader());
    requestData.append("<soap:Body>" + "<UploadImage" + " xmlns=\"http://example.org/\">" + "<ImageContent>").append(data).append("</ImageContent>\n").append("<imageExtenstion>jpg</imageExtenstion>").append("</UploadImage> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>");
    Log.d("reqData: ", requestData.toString());
    return requestData.toString().trim().getBytes();
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
            "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Hope it will help some one in the future

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in your chrome console and tell the output.

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '/_mobfiles/CLS_Account.asmx/UploadImage?';
    var base64 ='R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=='
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url + 'ImageContent='+base64+'&imageExtenstion=gif',true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    console.log(xmlhttp.response)
```

Try this too. If this also fails you gotta check the server. Atleast provide server method responsible for handling this.

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '/_mobfiles/CLS_Account.asmx/UploadImage?';
var base64 ='R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=='
xmlhttp.open("POST",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send('ImageContent="'+base64+'"&imageExtenstion="gif"');
console.log(xmlhttp)
```

Use a Get request and use

```
var base64 ='R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH%2BH09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw%3D%3D'
```

I am sure this should work. I am really sorry My bad I should haven't made such a stupid mistake/

Comment: GET http://www.sample.com/_mobfiles/CLS_Account.asmx/UploadImageTes…wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==&imageExtenstion=gif 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: status: 404
statusText: "OK"
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: and when put in url returns "System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw== to System.Byte.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: thank you my friend i will try to contact my web provider , i marked the answer

Comment: did it work? Now you  should just encoder ur base64 string.

Comment: no it still get the same server error so i think it is a server side error isn't it ?

Comment: Seems like that your Server isn't able to parse the variables. So it gives 500. I can't think of any other way  it can parse a Byte. I'll try with my custom controller tomorrow and give a solution and confirm if its a server problem.

Comment: and if you can get a server side solution as well to send it to my web developer i will be so grateful  , thanks for you help